# Highcharts - Item Parliament chart Integration in Angular 8

Tags: highcharts

Hi i am facing issue in integrating Item Parliament chart[Highcharts] in Angular. Type '[string, number]' has no properties in common with type 'XrangePointOptionsObject' in data field. But data field is given in sample code with string and number. Please help in implementing the same in angular with sample code

Comment: Please reproduce the issue that you faced while implementing on some online editor.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.